# Configuring CentOS apache server to default to a specific port for ExpressJS and Node

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, configuration

I have a webapp built on ExpressJS and NodeJS that runs on `port 5000` of my server, accessible via web by typing: `http://00.000.000.000:5000`. When you go to my non-port IP address (`http://00.000.000.000`) it shows the CentOS Apache setup welcome page.

I've tried running my Express app on `port 80`, but I get an `Address In Use` error.

What do I have to do to set up CentOS so that accessing its IP address at `00.000.000.000` loads up my Express app? I've tried adding `port 5000` to listeners in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file but this did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You got the `Address In Use` because Apache already uses port 80.

If you want to access your Express app throught port 80, then you have to shutdown Apache and run your app on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to TCP ports (which port 80 is), you can only bind one process to a given port. The process in this case is Apache, so no other process can use it while Apache is bound to the port. You can use the command `netstat` with the `-t` switch to see TCP ports in use.

```
$ netstat -tapn | grep :80
tcp        0      0 :::80        :::*            LISTEN      7999/httpd
```

Here we can see Apache, `httpd`, is using the port. Also you can see the process ID (7999) for the process in the above output too.